# Why do scala REPL and Ammonite behave differently in this point and which behaviour is correct?

Tags: scala, ammonite

The Scala expression

```
.3.+(5)
```

evaluates to `5.3` as a result in Ammonite-REPL, as I expected. In the Scala REPL, though, it yields a syntax error, printing

```
scala> .3.+(5)
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but double literal found.
       $intp.3.+(5)
            ^
```

Intuitively, `.3.+(5)` seems to be a valid expression to me. Is there a bug in Ammonite or is it in the Scala REPL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That particular expression doesn't work in the Scala REPL, because it has a feature that allows you to call methods on the last expression that was output. The last expression in your REPL session must have been named `$intp`. This feature is typically used like this:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3, 4)
res14: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> .map(_ + 1)
res15: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4, 5)
```

In your case, the Scala REPL thinks you're trying to call a method named `.3` on the last output. I can't find anything in the Ammonite docs or by trying it out that suggests it supports this feature. That is, Ammonite doesn't support the example I pasted above, which is probably the less confusing way to do things.

Answer (score 2):

When you start an expression with a `.` in the regular Scala REPL, it tries to interpret it as though you try to invoke a method on the previous evaluation result.

So when you write `.3.+(5)` the REPL thinks you meant `resX.3.+(5)`, with `resX` being whatever was the last result the REPL returned.